# URLSession timed out prematurely with _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=60

Tags: ios

I have working code using a URLSession. I'm testing behaviour when the server does not respond and a request times out. I cannot make my request timeout greater than about 25 seconds.

```
let session: URLSession = {
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    config.timeoutIntervalForRequest = <various values in seconds I fill in>
    return URLSession(configuration: config)
}()
```

If I set timeoutIntervalForRequest=5 or 10 the request times out in 5 or 10 seconds and I see this EXPECTED error:

> Error : Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed
>   out." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x15e6d1020 {Error
>   Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}},
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://10.0.0.91:8084/margtest1/DatabaseServlet, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://10.0.0.91:8084/margtest1/DatabaseServlet, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.}

If I set timeoutIntervalForRequest=60 (or more) about 25 seconds after the request I see this error log:

> Error : Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed
>   out." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x12d896d50 {Error
>   Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=60, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}},
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://10.0.0.91:8084/margtest1/DatabaseServlet,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://10.0.0.91:8084/margtest1/DatabaseServlet,
>   _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=60, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.}
>
> CloudSync db DL failed. Sync failed.

The difference between these logs is that when the request times out earlier than **timeoutIntervalForRequest** I receive **_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=60**. The NSUnderlyingError is also different.

To recap, my requests time out within about 25 seconds even when I set timeoutIntervalForRequest > 25. When this happens I see -kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=60.

I've spent a couple of hours internet searching for an explanation or way to debug this. Can you suggest how to fix this or a method to debug such an issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you find any solution to this problem?